# COPERNICUS_S5P_OFFL_L3_NO2 image export convert unit to ppm

Tags: raster, google-earth-engine, convert, units

The image I exported from COPERNICUS_S5P_OFFL_L3_NO2 has values in mol/m^2
is there a way I could convert the unit to ppm?

How do you Convert from Molarity (M/m2) to Parts Per Million (ppm) ?

Answer (score -1):

I found the formula I would like to share it:
Molarity to parts per million (ppm)

PPM=(Molarity*Molar mass)/0.001

Molar Mass for No2 is 46

You could use it in raster calculator to convert the exported raster file.

Comment: Molarity is a chemistry concept to quantify solution concentration. How does that relate to Raster Calculator?